# Python indentation error in if statement

Tags: python

I have a following trouble in Python.

```
sister_age = 15

brother_age = 12

if sisiter_age > brother_age:
    print "sisiter is older"
    else:
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

if sisiter_age > brother_age:
    print "sisiter is older"
    else:

  File "<pyshell#5>", line 4
    else:
        ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

No matter how many times I try to change the index, it shows an error.

Comment: `else` needs to have the same indentation as its corresponding `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is something after the `else` statement, the `else` statement should be aligned with the `if` statement, not inside it.

Example -

```
if sisiter_age > brother_age:
    print "sisiter is older"
else:
```

Also, if you do not have (or need) anything inside the `else` statement, you should just remove it.